# find employees whoo don't play sports MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Suppose I have a table of employees in one MYSQL table

```
| CompanyId, EmployeeId, Employee Name |
```

And in another table, I have employees and sports

```
| CompanyId, Employee Id, Sport |
```

**So now I wanna find employee names of all people in a company that don't play some sport (say Football)**

Assume I've created a view to simplify querying:

View with left join where companyId and employeeId match, so that my view looks like:```

```
| CompanyId, EmployeeId, Employee Name, Sport |
```

where rows are duplicated for each sport like so

```
 01 | 017 | Dylan | Football
 01 | 017 | Dylan | Cricket
 01 | 017 | Dylan | Table Tennis
 01 | 007 | Tom   | Hockey
 01 | 007 | Tom   | Table Tennis
 01 | 011 | Mary  | null
```

e.g. get me all players from company 01 who don't play hockey should return Dylan and Mary

I've tried SELECT DISTINCT on the view, but that kills the performance for even smallish datasets (order of 1000 rows takes multiple seconds).
Assume an index on the id column in the left table used in the join (CompanyId, EmployeeId).

Comment: "I've tried..."  I don't see a query.

Answer (score 0):

`not exists` comes to mind:

```
select e.*
from employees e
where not exists (select 1
                  from sports s
                  where s.employeeid = e.employeeid and s.sport = 'football'
                 );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try `not exists`:

```
select e.* from employees e
where e.companyid = '01' 
and not exists (
  select 1 from sports s
  where s.companyid = e.ecompanyid and s.employeeid = e.employeeid and s.sport = 'football'
)
```

or with a left join of `employees` to a filtered result of `sports` that will return all the unmatched rows:

```
select e.* 
from employees e left join (
  select * from sports
  where sport = 'football'
) s on s.companyid = e.companyid and s.employeeid = e.employeeid
where e.company = '01' and s.employeeid is null
```

Answer (score 0):

NOT IN is also possible here.

```
SELECT e.name FROM employees e WHERE e.company = '01' AND e.employeeid NOT IN (
SELECT s.employeeid FROM sports s WHERE s.sport = 'football'
);
```